# React not re-rendering despite state being changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component, `App.js` that contains some state and functions which it passes to its children through properties. One of these state values contained within App is a `name`, which is set whenever the User's access token is successfully verified.

`name` is passed to a child component, `TopBar` as a property:

```
<div className="App">
    <Topbar name={this.state.name} isLoggedIn={this.isLoggedIn}></Topbar>
</div>
```

`App.isLoggedIn()` checks `document.cookie` for a JsonWebToken, verifies it, and updates `App` state to set the value of `name`. `isLoggedIn()` is called from the child component TopBar like so:

```
class TopBar extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        [ ... ]
    }

    [ ... ]
    // This is the issue I believe, but I can't think of an alternative
    async componentDidMount() {
        let result = await this.props.isLoggedIn();
        this.setState({'login' : result});
    }

    render() {
return (
    { this.state.login &&
        <li className="nav-item">Welcome <a href="#account">{this.props.name}</a> | <a href="">Logout</a></li>
    }
    {!this.state.login &&
        <li className="navItem"><a href="#login" onClick={this.showModal}>Sign In</a></li>
    }
);
```

Problem being, when isLoggedIn() is called, the `name` property *does* change, however nothing re-renders until a reload of the webpage. Using react dev tools I can see that the proper `name` value is getting into `TopBar` as a property.

I understand that changing properties shouldn't trigger a re-render, but the properties *are* state in the parent component, so surely changing their values should trigger a re-render of the entire application?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making componentDidMount async you can outsource your code into a helper function

```js
async checkIfUserIsLoggedIn() {
     let result = await this.props.isLoggedIn();
     this.setState({'login' : result});
}

componentDidMount() {
     checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
}
```